# IE z-index Issue

Tags: css, internet-explorer, cross-browser, z-index

[alt text http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/3876/screenshot20100621at110.png](http://img706.imageshack.us/img706/3876/screenshot20100621at110.png)

Looking good here in the result, but I can't achieve the same in IE. Is there any workaround for this?

JsFiddle for this: http://jsfiddle.net/3f3Xa/

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: What version of IE are you having issues with?

Comment: The link is to jsfiddle's main page currently

Comment: IE6 and IE7. Whoops, link fixed.

Comment: Looks consistent to me in FX 3 vs IE6. Can you be more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using IE 6 ?
It is a bug of IE 6 or 7, so far the code work well in IE 7.

Maybe you should find more information in [this page](http://www.quirksmode.org/bugreports/archives/2006/01/Explorer_z_index_bug.html)

Answer (score 0):

You should set a z-index for every element in IE.

```
body {
  z-index: 0;
}
```

or

```
* {
  z-index: 0;
}
```